# SymPy cannot rearrange results while solving a system of equations about Stackelberg game

Tags: sympy, equation-solving, game-theory

Function f (assume n=3 for simplicity):
[image]

There are 3 symbols related to entities, corresponding to `x[j](j=1,2,3)` respectively. `R` and `c` is other symbols, which can be treated like constant for now.  I try to diff f w.r.t `x[j]`, and solve the results equations together and get `x[j]=g(R,c)`. However, sympy cannot rearrange or split `x[j]` from the equation.

Derivatives:
[image]

**Expected Results**:
[image]

```
from sympy import *
import sympy as sym
real_n = 3
x = IndexedBase('x')
j, k, n = symbols('j,k n', cls=Idx)
f = x[j]*Symbol("R")/Sum(x[k],(k,1,real_n))-Symbol("c")*x[j]
equ = diff(f,x[j])

ee = solve([equ.subs(j,1),equ.subs(j,2),equ.subs(j,3)], (x[1],x[2],x[3]))
simplify(ee)
```

**Sympy's result**:

```
{x[1]: (R*Sum(x[k], (k, 1, 3)) - c*Sum(x[k], (k, 1, 3))**2)/(R*Sum(KroneckerDelta(1, k), (k, 1, 3))),
 x[2]: (R*Sum(x[k], (k, 1, 3)) - c*Sum(x[k], (k, 1, 3))**2)/(R*Sum(KroneckerDelta(2, k), (k, 1, 3))),
 x[3]: (R*Sum(x[k], (k, 1, 3)) - c*Sum(x[k], (k, 1, 3))**2)/(R*Sum(KroneckerDelta(3, k), (k, 1, 3)))}
```

[image]

I tried to check if the indexed symbol caused the error, and wrote x[i] as 3 different symbols, but it still didn't work.

```
from sympy import *

a, b, c = symbols('a b c', cls=Idx)
R = symbols("R")
eq1 = diff(a/(a+b+c)-a*R,a)
eq2 = diff(b/(a+b+c)-b*R,b)
eq3 = diff(c/(a+b+c)-c*R,c)
print(eq1,"\n",eq2,"\n",eq3)
solve([eq1,eq2,eq3], [a,b,c])
```

Output:

```
-R + 1/(a + b + c) - a/(a + b + c)**2 
 -R + 1/(a + b + c) - b/(a + b + c)**2 
 -R + 1/(a + b + c) - c/(a + b + c)**2
[]
```

Is there something wrong with my approach? Is it possible to approach this problem in SymPy from another angle?

Any suggestions for the solution of equations are also most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doit` to expand the summation and then solve:

```
In [6]: solve([equ.subs(j,1).doit(),equ.subs(j,2).doit(),equ.subs(j,3).doit()], (x[1],x[2],x[3]))
Out[6]: 
⎡⎛         ____          ⎞⎤
⎢⎜        ╱  2           ⎟⎥
⎢⎜R + 3⋅╲╱  R    2⋅R  2⋅R⎟⎥
⎢⎜─────────────, ───, ───⎟⎥
⎣⎝     18⋅c      9⋅c  9⋅c⎠⎦
```

Comment: Thank you for your generous help. It's very inspirational to see the right result. However, there still empty result for my machine , after I tried `doit` by myself. My runtime infos: sympy version:1.11.1, 'macOS-13.0.1-arm64', python: '3.8.15'. And I try the code in another machine with Windows 10 python3.8, it still cannot get the result. I wonder what platform or runtime are you using? Thanks. [tried_results_link](https://imgur.com/a/3Pnr53d)

Comment: I think it's because I'm using SymPy from git. A bug was fixed but the fix has not been released yet.

Comment: I tried the the latest sympy version in git, sympy==1.12.dev0 for now. However, it's still empty results.

Comment: In order to help others with the same problem, here is my final solution: I turned to Matlab, it gave me the right and expected result for the code that does exactly the same thing. But Oscar Benjamin's `doit` function really helped me

Comment: Actually there was no bug. The code works with older versions of sympy. I just tested 1.10 and 1.11 as well as sympy master. I just used the first 7 lines of your code and then copied the line that I showed and it gave the same output that I showed before. If you were getting an empty result then you did not run the same code as shown so I can't say what the problem was.